# Need to log identifiers from select query recordset along with date/time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to log all records generated by a sql select statement in an SSRS report into a table for later reference at the time the report is run.

One idea is to append the unique ID to the reference table and then perform the full query with the additional data for the full record set, but i feel like there is probably a better way.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an xy problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/ You want to have a report run a query and store the data in a table so that the report can access the data it just inserted. Something seems very off to me here.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a `STORED PROCEDURE` for your SSRS report instead of hard coding the query in the RDL. Then, you could leverage the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause and log the query execution, and return the results. The proc would look something like this:

```
create procedure myProc (@param1 int)
as
begin

declare @resultTable table (id int, c1 char(4), c2 char(4))

insert into myloggingtable
output INSERTED.id, INSERTED.c2, INSERTED.c3 into @resultTable 
select 
   id,
   c1,
   c2,
   RunDateTime = getdate(),
from SomeTable
where id = @param1 


select * from @resultTable 

end
```

Here, I would have an auto-incremented key on the myloggingtable and the RunDateTime would be logged as the execution time.

Comment: This seems very close.  The example would be a query that pulled Customer ID, Name, address, phone to generate a letter.  The SSRS report generates the letter through the procedure while writing each customer ID and date to the logging file.  This allows you to wait 6 months before sending another letter to the customer.

Comment: Your comment cut off @TennSqlGuy